# How can i target the input tag in the second td of a table(input tags are dynamic-appended base on the user needs)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a dynamic table that looks like this
[image]

Now I want my code to execute when the user select something in the select tag under the item name column and store the data in the input tag under the item id column using ajax base on selected item.All my codes seems working well except for targeting the right element to pass the data from json file.Heres my code:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select.items', function(){
    let selectedItem = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url:'php/retrieve_itemID.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {selectedItem : selectedItem},
      dataType:"json",
      success: function(data){
        $("#request_table tr td input.item-id").each(function() {
            $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input.item-id').val(data.item_id);
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the scope of `this` within the AJAX `success` handler is not the same as the outer event handler. As such `this` does not reference the `select.items` element which raised the `change` event.

To fix this create a variable which holds a reference to the `tr` closest to the `select`. Then within the `success` handler you can `find()` the relevant `input` whose value you want to update. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('change', 'select.items', function() {
  let selectedItem = $(this).val();
  let $row = $(this).closest('tr');

  $.ajax({
    url: 'php/retrieve_itemID.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      selectedItem: selectedItem
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      $row.find('input.item-id').val(data.item_id);
    }
  });
});
```